# pyspark - if statement inside select

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Following code finds maximum length of all columns in dataframe `df`.

**Question**: In the code below how can we check the max length of only string columns?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length, max

df=df.select([max(length(col(name))) for name in df.schema.names])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition that tests for the `dataType` of `df.schema`. For example:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, '2', '1'),
        (1, '4', '2'),
        (1, '2', '3'),
    ],
    ['col1','col2','col3']
)

df.select([
    max(length(col(schema.name))).alias(f'{schema.name}_max_length') 
    for schema in df.schema 
    if schema.dataType == StringType()
])
    
+---------------+---------------+
|col2_max_length|col3_max_length|
+---------------+---------------+
|              1|              1|
+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Your code works with hard coded example (thank you - my upvote). But when `df` is loaded with a `csv` file, it ignores the `if` statement. For that, I have posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75525825/1232087)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `schema.names`, you can use `schema.fields` that returns list of StructField’s which you can iterate through and get name and type of each field.

```
df.select([max(length(col(field.name))) for field in df.schema.fields if field.dataType.typeName == "string"])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df = df.select([max(length(col(name))) for (name, type) in df.dtypes if type == 'string'])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.