# pyspark - select() function ignoring if statement

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-storage-account

Thanks to user @DerekO, [his](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75487254/1232087) following example is correctly getting max lengths of only `varchar` columns. But when I use the same example with `df` loaded with a `csv` file it ignores the `if` statement and calculates the max lengths of all columns (including the ones that are integers, doubles etc.)

**Question**: **Without** creating custom schema, how can we improve the EXAMPLE 2 below, so it displays the max lengths of only the varchar columns

**Example 1**:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length, max
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
    
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, '2', '1'),
        (1, '4', '82'),
        (1, '2', '3'),
    ],
    ['col1','col2','col3']
)

df.select([
    max(length(col(schema.name))).alias(f'{schema.name}_max_length') 
    for schema in df.schema 
    if schema.dataType == StringType()
])
    
+---------------+---------------+
|col2_max_length|col3_max_length|
+---------------+---------------+
|              1|              2|
+---------------+---------------+
```

**Example 2**:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length, max
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.read.option("delimiter", ',').option("header", 'true').option("escape", '"').option("inferSchema", 'true')\
      .csv("abfss://myContainer@myStorageAccountName" + '.dfs.core.windows.net/' + myFile_path)

df = df.select([max(length(col(schema.name))).alias(f'{schema.name}')
    for schema in df.schema 
    if schema.dataType == StringType()
])

display(df)

#The above code displays lengths of all columns even though `csv` file contains non-varchar columns, as well, as shown below:

for schema in df.schema:
  print(schema.name+" , "+str(schema.dataType))

#Output: The csv has about 80 columns. For brevity I am displaying only the few here
Field , StringType
Field2 , StringType
Field3 , StringType
Field4 , IntegerType
Field5 , DoubleType
Field6 , LongType
Field7, StringType
Field8 , StringType
Field9 , DoubleType
.....
.....
```

Comment: I am having trouble reproducing the behavior you're describing even when using a csv file. is it possible you could provide a sample of your csv (or a dummy csv similar to yours), even just the first one or two rows and maybe the first 10 fields?

Comment: @DerekO With smaller files it may work. It may have something to do with file size. My csv is `6GB` with over `10M` records and 120 columns of which about `30` of them are non-varchar. But it's still a mystery that the second `for` loop in `example 2` above correctly displays the data types. But the the first `for` loop inside select statement in the same example, is treating all columns to be of varchar type. Maybe, something to do with using `for` loop inside `select()` for larger data files. Is there a way to do it without using `for` loop inside `select()`  - or some other workaround?

Comment: @nam, can you provide the information like where you are executing the above code? in synapse, databricks or local?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula It's inside Azure Databricks.

Comment: i don't really understand how the size of the csv file could impact the schema of the dataframe... perhaps the for loop isn't being executed when we think it is due to lazy evaluation, but i am highly skeptical that's the cause. that being said, i will see if we can approach the problem without using a for `loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I am just guessing at this point, but perhaps using `==` isn't the best practice, and we should use `isinstance` instead.

```
df.select([
    max(length(col(schema.name))).alias(f'{schema.name}_max_length') 
    for schema in df.schema 
    if isinstance(schema.dataType, StringType)
])
```